# Self-signed certificate for a IdP-initiated SAML SSO

Tags: certificates, openssl, sso, saml

We act as a Service Provider in a SAML SSO integration with our customers. During the dev and stage testing, we usually exchange metadata files and SSO endpoints.

When forming our metadata we use the `openssl` command-line tool to generate a self-signed certificate which we set the value of the `X509Certificate` node to:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server.pem -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.pem -out server.crt
```

Now, the **question is**, when going to *production*, should we obtain a legit certificate from a third-party, or we can simply regenerate a new self-signed certificate? What potential security or other implications could we have if use a self-signed one?

Note: we, as a service provider, don't send SAML messages in this kind of IdP-initiated setup.

Using Python, Django and [`djangosaml2` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2) (if this is relevant).

Comment: Just make sure that you track certificate renewals otherwise SSO may stop working one fine day and not all products provide a good error message in such scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [Self-signed certificates are fine, and even recommended at least in some contexts.](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/X.509+Certificates+in+Metadata#X.509CertificatesinMetadata-Requirements) Use long validity times to avoid key rollover problems, and if RSA, use at least 2048-bit keys.

SAML 2.0 includes the certificate that should be used for signature validation and as an encryption recipient *as a part of the SAML metadata* (technically, within the `EntityDescriptor`).

The entity that uses the metadata is supposed to validate the metadata in a "known good" way. This could, for example, be by only downloading it over a trusted channel (for example through HTTPS with normal certificate validation), or by storing a copy of the metadata locally having obtained and verified it in some other trusted manner.

In practice, metadata tends to also be XML signed, which provides an additional layer of integrity validation above and beyond the protection afforded by for example HTTPS. (This is a good thing particularly given how many implementations appear to require actually manually downloading and storing metadata in places where it could easily be modified, accidentally or maliciously. At least then the XML signature fails to validate, causing the metadata to be rejected rather than potentially incorrect metadata to be used.)

If you are unable to exchange SAML metadata while ensuring the integrity of said metadata, then you have a significant bootstrapping problem, to the point that I'm not even sure it's *possible* to use SAML in a secure manner. If you can't trust the certificate that is part of the metadata, that implies that you cannot trust anything *else* in the metadata *either*, including for example the endpoint URIs.

If you are able to exchange SAML metadata while ensuring its integrity, then by definition it contains a trusted certificate blob, which is *intended* (subject to restrictions stated in the metadata) to be used to:

- Validate the signature on any incoming SAML data, including authentication requests and authentication responses, *from* the entity for which the metadata is generated
- Serve as a recipient key for encrypted SAML data *to* the entity for which the metadata is generated (note that encrypted SAML XML is not supported by all implementations)

As that certificate (from the trusted metadata) is by definition trusted, **using a CA-signed certificate provides no significant benefit over using a self-signed certificate. There is thus no reason to use a CA-signed certificate, and some reason not to** (for example, on Internet2 it is recommended to use certificates with at least 10 years validity; I'm not aware of any commercial CA providing certificates with that long validity).

**To mention but one admittedly somewhat anecdotal example, Microsoft's Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) appears to be perfectly happy about self-signed certificates in SAML metadata;** I have done on the SP side pretty much exactly the same that you have, in testing, with ADFS acting as the IdP.